# Laptop power button not working but battery discharge pinhole button is starting the computer, what might be the issue here?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, acer-aspire

I have an **Acer Aspire A515-51G**, the issue is suddenly the power button has stopped working, the battery is charging, but the *pinhole* that they have given; pressing it, actually starts the computer; strange ? but doesn't fix the issue - to start again i have to press the button again.  what might be the issue here? My drivers are up to date - in fact it doesn't even seem an issue with driver at all - I suspect some hardware issue related to power supply

What might be causing it ? anything I can do to find out the issue ?

Comment: The button is a soft button, not a switch. So the button has probably failed.

Comment: is this how the pinhole suppose to work ? is pressing pinhole actually starts the laptop ? i thought it was just for internal battery reset

Comment: I do not know about the pinhole but the power button probably needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The power button for that machine is embedded in the keyboard.

See:    [Acer Aspire keyboard](https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/acer-aspire-5-15-6-laptop-iron-intel-core-i7-12650h-1tb-ssd-16gb-ram-windows-11/17160456?cmp=knc-s-71700000055465140&gad_source=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI49Tav8WthAMVAQutBh1kVQb2EAQYBCABEgLimfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

You need to replace the keyboard.

A local service shop can do this, or the place where you purchased it may be able to service it.

See if warranty is available to you.

I have done this on my own computer and all remains working.

Comment: Thanks , it's about 5 year old laptop, don't have warranty anymore — probably will have to take it to technician; I think it's not just keyboard issue, something seems very strange to me how the pinhole thing is starting the computer - when it was supposed to reset the internal battery — I will write about whatever happens, but i must say I'm never buying another acer laptop ever - i have so far purchased 3, all of them have some design flaws, like - frequent keyboard failures, screen hinge is weak, on steel rim there is always some micro electric current - so awful 

Comment: It is difficult to assess from here what fault might be inside to affect the way the reset button works.  As we both note, a computer repair shop may be able to sort out why this occurs.